# Windows batch commands is not executed through Jenkins in Windows 7 after converting the agent into service

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, windows-7, jenkins-agent

While trying to execute the following batch command through Jenkins to modify the XML using a PowerShell script,

```
powershell.exe "C:\jenkins\workspace\TemplateJob\Scripts\Common\Prerequsites\Powershell\PowershellScripts\ModifyXML.ps1" "C:\jenkins\workspace\TemplateJob\Scripts\TestNgXML\RegressionTests\Regression.xml" "%Target_Browser%"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Unable to connect to the remote server"
```

But the same command is working fine in Windows 8 through Jenkins and working fine in windows 7 also if the slave agent is launched as Web Start (`Slave-agent.jnlp`).

After enabling "Allow service to interact with desktop" also issue exist.

Please find the following example: ModifyXML.ps1 which will update the parameter value in the given XML with the parameter value using XPath.

`Regression.xml`:

```xml
<suite><parameter name="browser" value="ie" /></suite>
```

`ModifyXML.ps1`:

```
param($path, $browser)

$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path) # Getting "Unable to connect to the remote server" error in this line
$xpathbrowser = "/suite/parameter[@name='browser']/@value" 
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes($xpathbrowser)
foreach ($node in $nodes) {
    if ($node -ne $null) {
        if ($node.NodeType -eq "Element") {
            $node.InnerXml = $browser
        } else {
            $node.Value = $browser
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the contents of `ModifyXML.ps1`? Where does it throw the error?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should be using the parameter `-File` for running PowerShell scripts.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Same script with same parameter is working fine in Windows 8. In windows 7 also working fine if jenkins slave running as jnlp agent not as service. Only problem with Jenkins service in windows 7.

Comment: Please do not post code or other information relevant to your question in comments. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Powershell script ModifyXML.ps1 which is used to modify the xml parameter value. Please find the sample in question

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yeah done.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. For some reason, XML transformation stopped working.

This is my original code:

```
function UpdateConfigValue($FileName, $xpath, $value) {

    $doc =  [xml](Get-Content $FileName) # no XML transformation any more

    $nodes = $doc.SelectNodes($xpath)

        foreach ($node in $nodes) {
            if ($node -ne $null) {
                if ($node.NodeType -eq "Element") {
                    $node.InnerXml = $value
                }
                else {
                    $node.Value = $value
                }
            }
        }

    $doc.save($FileName)
}
```

I tried different approaches and finally ended up with the following solution that works for me:

```
function UpdateConfigValue($FileName, $xpath, $value) {

    $fullpath = Join-Path $(get-location) $FileName # full path to the XML file

    [System.Xml.XmlDocument]$file = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $file.load($fullpath)

    $node = $file.SelectSingleNode($xpath)
    if ($node -ne $null) {
        if ($node.NodeType -eq "Element") {
            $node.InnerXml = $value
        }
        else {
            $node.value = $value
        }       
    }

    $file.save($fullpath)
}
```